# Memory Leak in C# Socket application

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, memory, memory-leaks

I am trying to write an Server application which is listening on a particular port and waiting for devices to hit that port.Device connects every 30 seconds Once a device connects the device sends its MAC address. But the problem is the memory keeps on increasing and never frees up.

```
class Server
{
    Object threadLock = new Object();
    bool stopListening = false;
    Socket clientSocket = null;

    private  void StartDeviceListener()
    {

        try
        {
            // create the socket
            clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                             SocketType.Stream,
                                             ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // bind the listening socket to the port
            IPEndPoint ep1 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 60000);
            clientSocket.LingerState = new LingerOption(false, 0);

            clientSocket.Bind(ep1);
            clientSocket.Listen(10); //Waiting for Devices to connect.

            do
            {
                // start listening
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for device connection on {0}....", 60000);
                Socket deviceSocket = clientSocket.Accept();
                //Console.WriteLine(deviceSocket.
                #region ThreadPool

                // ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ProcessRequest, (Object)deviceSocket);
                Thread ts = new Thread(ProcessRequest);
                ts.IsBackground = true;
                ts.Start((Object)deviceSocket);
                ts.Join();
                #endregion
            } while (!stopListening);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("exception... : " + ex.Message);
            StartDeviceListener();
        }

        finally
        {
            if (clientSocket != null) { clientSocket.Close(); clientSocket = null; }
        }

    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        try
        {
            stopListening = true;
            if (clientSocket != null)
            {
                clientSocket.Disconnect(false);
                clientSocket = null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("exception : " + ex.Message);
        }
    }


    void ProcessRequest(Object args)
    {
        using (Socket deviceSocket = args as Socket)
        {
            try
            {

                //lock the thread while we are creating the client IO Interface Manager
                lock (threadLock)
                {
                    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];
                    // Read from buffer
                    int count = deviceSocket.Receive(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                    String macAddress = "";//mac address sent by the device:
                    if (count > 0)
                    {
                        Encoding encoder = Encoding.ASCII;
                        int size = 0;
                        while (count > 0)
                        {
                            size += count;
                            // get string
                            macAddress += encoder.GetString(readBuffer, 0, count).Trim();
                            // Read from buffer
                            count = 0;
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} trying to connect....", macAddress));
                    }
                    deviceSocket.Close();
                    readBuffer = null;
                }
                //threadLock = null;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("exception : " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        args = null;
    }

  public  void Start()
    {
        StartDeviceListener();
    }
}`
```

[image: Initial Server running]

[image: Initial Memory Consumption]

[image: Device Connecting]
[image: Memory Consumption After Initial Connection]

[image: Device Connection]

[image: Memory Consumption After Multiple Connection]

Comment: Have you tried to start garbage collector manually? http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.gc.collect.aspx

Comment: @Dimitry : if you have to start garbage collecting manually, you are doing something very bad or very strange. It's trully exceptionnal calling the garbage collector yourself is a good idea.

Comment: Falanwe: it is ok to do it, when you are experimenting. Finding memory leaks is experiment. I meant that may be garbage collector had not run yet  and that is why memory keeps increasing

Comment: I did try calling GC.Collect() ; although it does free up the memory it causes the Virtual Memory to go up . Like @Falanwe said its not a good idea to call GC manually . I want to make sure that the sockets and all the resources are freed when the thread exits. But it looks like something is not getting freed.

Comment: Try to do tousends connection

Comment: It's a good idea to call GC manually, because as you sad it does free up memory, so there is no leak. Now you can remove GC.Collect() and go to sleep :)

Comment: @Dmitry: As an experiment it's okay. I thought you were meaning it as a solution.

Comment: This is a hard thing to determine strictly from the working set.  The garbage collector will clear things up when it thinks it needs to, not when you've released them.  Just because the memory is going up doesn't necessarily mean there is a leak. It's not c++ where the memory is manually managed. And this is different depending on operating systems, on a server system .net will garbage collect less aggressivly giving you more throughput. Every time it gc's it has to stop all processing so you get skips in your processing.  The best bet here, like suggested, is to use a profiler.

Comment: So 100kb are added and this is a memory leak?

Comment: @rahul - This doesn't look like a real problem.  Memory only gets collected when it's needed, or whenever the GC feels like it.  To know if it's a real memory leak you need to us a memory profiler because it hooks into the app at the beginning and end and can tell you when a real memory leak occurs.  Using GC.Collect() when profiling is perfectly fine because you are only doing it to see what memory is waiting to be collected.  You wouldn't do this in a production app.  Further, it doesn't matter what the Virtual memory is, this is not a real allocated memory number.

Comment: @rahul - the only important number is Private Bytes (Private Working Set) as that is the amount of actual memory commited.

Comment: ok let me do some more testing with a profiler and get back. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Have you tried not creating your own thread and using the ThreadPool (a little better) or even Tasks (a lot better, but depends on the .Net version you're using) to do the job?

Comment: Another problem, might be related: doing `ts.Start(...); ts.Join();` is making this single-threaded. And the full-lenght lock on `threadLock` makes that double sure.

Comment: @Falanwe : I did try ThreadPool with similar results.

Answer (score 1):

> But the problem is the memory keeps on increasing and never frees up.

That is still a far cry from a memory-leak. You're probably chasing a problem that does not exist.

In the last shot you still have a working set of 10MB, that's practically zero.
When you really want to find/solve memory issues, use a profiler.

Comment: It looks fine with just 1 device connecting ; but if i have like 4K -5K devices trying to connect the problem gets magnified.

Comment: Magnified how much, does it level off or do you get OOM exceptions?

Comment: If i let the server run for a day it keeps increasing upto 1 GB ; and i cant connect to any device after that. so i have a scheduled task which restarts the m/c and the server once a day

Comment: But I'm guessing that's another version (more code) than whats posted here. I see a single-threaded server but no obvious leak. The problem could be in that other code...